# How can i suppress output from a command in bash without making its variable empty

Tags: bash, stderr, io-redirection

```
check="$(cat "$HOME/log.txt" | grep 'some_string')"

if [ -z "${check}" ] ; then
  echo "string not found"
else
  echo "string found"
fi
```

In my bash script , i am checking for a string in a file and it outputs if the string was found or not by checking if the variable is empty ot not . Pretty simple .
So the thing is when this $HOME/log.txt file is absent , it outputs

```
cat: /home/user/log.txt: No such file or directory
string not found
```

Not really wrong here but i want to suppress that "No such file or directory" message , i just simply thought of using `&>/dev/null` alongside cat command to suppress this but then if i do this `check="$(cat "$HOME/log.txt" &>/dev/null | grep 'some_string')"` , the resulting `$check` variable always becomes empty and hence it always says string not found even when its actually there

How do i can suppress the output of cat command and retain its variable value ?

Comment: Replace by `&>/dev/null` by `2>/dev/null` ?

Comment: That seems to work well , thanks . if you can put that up as answer that  i will definitely accept it . A short and simple difference between ```&>/dev/null``` && ```2>/dev/null``` would make it perfect

Comment: `grep 'some_string' "$HOME/log.txt" 2>/dev/null` should do the same without the cat and the pipe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `&>/dev/null` by `2>/dev/null`:

```
check="$(cat "$HOME/log.txt" 2>/dev/null | grep 'some_string')"
```

Here is a brief summary of how redirections work:

- `2>/dev/null` will only redirect standard error;
- `1>/dev/null` or `>/dev/null` will only redirect standard output.
- `&>/dev/null` will redirect both standard output and standard error (not POSIX);

Comment: consider also including `>/dev/null`  in the explanation for completeness

Comment: adding to the answer, `1>/dev/null` commonly `>/dev/null` will only redirect standard output. also note that `&>/dev/null` is not in POSIX standard and may not work in some shells.